# After Migrate Magento1 Database Into magento 2 product is not open?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, database, product-attribute

**When edit the product from backend is not open getting error**

```
Class Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Media does not exist
```

How i solve this please tell me

Comment: which tool are u using?

Comment: uber migration tool